# Where Moodle is rendering templates

Tags: php, moodle

I'm having problem with understanding where moodle is rendering templates.
I have page which url endings: /enrol/index.php?id=4 so i assume that template is from enrol catalogue. 
In page from this url I want to add some custom php and html , can you tell me where I can find frontend of this page and backend ?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Moodle 2.5, the following code in `enrol\index.php`, line #57, is responsible for retrieving all the content to be displayed:

```
foreach($enrolinstances as $instance) {
    if (!isset($enrols[$instance->enrol])) {
        continue;
    }
    $form = $enrols[$instance->enrol]->enrol_page_hook($instance);
    if ($form) {
        $forms[$instance->id] = $form;
    }
}
```

The actual content is printed to the users on #line 90 with

```
foreach ($forms as $form) {
    echo $form;
}
```

Anywhere around here you can inject custom content ..., ideally, your code should go after the header and before the footer, e.g.

```
echo $OUTPUT->header();
echo $OUTPUT->heading(get_string('enrolmentoptions','enrol'));

... your code goes here

echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you helped me very much! Can you tell me please also how to get logged user data like his login , name etc? 
It is possible or i have to write special Query for that ?

Comment: You can get information about the logged-in user using the `$USER` object. You can do a `print_r($USER)` to see all the available fields.